# Changing from hover to click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, click, hover

I've recently implemented a small box on my website at the bottom of the page to expand when the mouse hovers over it... This is the code and it all works great.

**CSS**

```
#box{
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:20px;
    left: 33%;
    right: 33%;
    min-width: 32%;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: #353535;
}
```

**javascript**

```
$('#box').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '220px'
    }, 150);
},function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '20px'
    }, 500);
});
```

But I'm curious about how I would go about changing this to open and close on a click rather than the mouse hovering over it?

I've edited it to...

```
$('#box').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '220px'
    }, 150);
},function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '20px'
    }, 500);
});
```

And this works to open the box. But I can't get it to close again with another click.

So close yet so far! :P

Comment: What library are you using?  Is it possible that the hover function expects two parameters and the click function expects only one?

Comment: I see you've now added the jQuery tag... good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work

```
$('#box').toggle(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '220px'
    }, 150);
},function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '20px'
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably just use the [toggle event handler](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) instead of the click event like so:

```
$('#box').toggle(function() {...}, function() {...});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$('#box').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
    $(this).hide();
    return;
  }

  $(this).animate({height: '220px'}, 150);
});
```

On the click, it will hide the element if visible else animate it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but this did not work. When I clicked on the box at the bottom of the screen instead of it popping up it just vanished.