# Javascript - From hover to click

Tags: javascript, hover, click

How can I change this from hover to click?

```
$(function(){
    $('ul#menu li').hover(function(){
        //$('#drop' , this).css('display','block');
         $(this).children('ul').delay(20).slideDown(600);
    }, function(){
         $(this).children('ul').delay(20).slideUp(600);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g7ead5x/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing from hover to click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943886/changing-from-hover-to-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`click` only takes a single handler; `hover` is unique in that it takes two. You'll need to use a single handler:

```
$(function(){
    $('ul#menu li').on('click', function(){
         // note using slideToggle which automatically switches
         // btwn up/down
         $(this).children('ul').delay(20).slideToggle(600);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8g7ead5x/1/

---

Or, per the dupe, you can use `.toggle`:

```
$(function(){
    $('ul#menu li').toggle(function(){
        //$('#drop' , this).css('display','block');
         $(this).children('ul').delay(20).slideDown(600);
    }, function(){
         $(this).children('ul').delay(20).slideUp(600);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's got a few bugs, doesn't it? You click once and the menu slides down, but if you click the last item that's supposed to open another menu it closes the first one...

Comment: You'll have to stop the click from bubbling up. That's outside the scope of your question though. (Also that is covered in extensive detail in roughly 12000 other questions here on StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 0):

<del>Just change the name of the function `hover` to `click`. It's part of jQuery.</del>

---

Use @Mathletics example. The `click` function only takes in one function, so you have to alter your code. I revised your Fiddle with a working example ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8g7ead5x/3/)), so now you have a third option.

Comment: Can you include a `console.log` inside the `click`-function to make sure that the function is called?

Comment: what? lol I don't know much about js... would it help if I posted a fiddle with the whole thing so you could see the script in action?

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful.

Comment: Fiddle added. What to make it so that you have to click the menu to trigger the slideUp/Down. Thanks.

Comment: @bvx89 you can't change it directly because the `click` handler doesn't take two methods, unlike `hover` which does. You'll have to re-write the handler to toggle between the states.

Comment: @Mathletics you are correct. I altered my answer and referred to yours as well.